# Form value passing without using input tags

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I made 2 views, they both got forms. the first one is for basic details, then adds a textbox with a numeric value.

say for example:
Family name:
Members:

submit button: Proceed

then afterwards, i pass that(as `$data=array('name'=>$_POST['familyname'],'members'=>$_POST['family_members'])`; to a controller then to a new view.

then i loop here,

```
for($counter=1;$counter<$members+1;$counter++)
{
echo "<input type='text' name='membername$counter'/>";
}
```

so after which ill pass it again to yet another controller function.
but then my question is, how would i pass the $name and `$members` value together with the new values from the 2nd form.

Without using hidden input types and storing them as their value

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) are for.

> Sessions are a simple way to store data for individual users against a unique session ID. This can be used to persist state information between page requests. Session IDs are normally sent to the browser via session cookies and the ID is used to retrieve existing session data.

Comment: I would argue the session should **only** be used for identifying information, not storing intermediate form data.

Comment: Any particular reason why?

Comment: I thought $session was used for important data like when a user logs in and you use session so only a logged in user can access certain pages.

am i wrong?

Comment: It can be used for that and more. They aren't limited to certain tasks.

Comment: @JohnConde When you store intermediate data in the session (or cookies) you might run into issues when you start two or more instances of this form. One will end up overwriting the other.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen That sounds like more of an organizations/business logic concern then a reason not to use sessions here.

Comment: It's a usability concern. If I start the same form funnel twice I don't expect the data streams to get mixed up. - - Let's say you have a list of items with a filter and pagination. You open the page twice because you're looking for `boats` in one and `sports cars` in the other. If that page shared it's data in a session or cookie and you starting leafing through the pages you'd get very confused. Usually this is implemented correctly because filter and pagination is implemented using only `GET` parameters. OPs question is an extension of the same underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep passing all the information along. There are several ways to do it.

The *easy* way is to create a `<input type="hidden">` field in the 2nd form that has all the information of the first form serialized.

Something like:

```
$first_form_data = $_POST["..."];
echo '<input type="hidden" name="first_form_data"
  value="' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($first_form_data)) . '" />';
```

I've used `json_encode` as a serializer. You can also use `serialize` or any serializer applicable for this format.

To unserialize the data use `json_decode` and `unserialize` respectively.

---

A more complex and involved solution would have you store the data elsewhere and reference it by a token of some sort, and pass just the token along. This can be useful if the data-set is so large you don't want to pass it along ever time.

Comment: Where do i initialize $first_form_data? 2nd view? or the controller for the 2nd view?

Comment: `$first_form_data` is a variable name I picked to indicate you're collecting all the data from the first form and injecting it in the second form. How that works out in practice depends on how you're linking the two forms together. If you're unsure: is there any code you can share?